# Transpose Excel and create new column based on the transposed header values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, transpose

I have an excel file:

[image]

And I am trying to transpose the file and create a new column with values based on the header values. So, I want one column (number) to have all the numbers and the values `m0,m1,m2,m3` to be added to a new column with the header `Month`:

[image]

It seems quite difficult to find anything online. Do I need a macros for that? Ideally, I want to do that in excel using the classic functions.

Comment: Search for 'UnPivot Data', transposing is different to what you are after

Comment: And you will be able UNPivot the data, and also sort and rename the columns, using `Power Query`, a free Microsoft provided add-in for Excel 2010.  The query settings will be recorded and can be used repetitively.

Answer (score 1):

You can always map a 2-D table into a single row or a single column with a formula.

Say your data is in cols **A** through **D**, In **E1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$1,ROUNDUP(ROW()/(COUNTA(A:A)-1),0))
```

and copy downwards.  In **F1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$9999,MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(A:A)-1)+1,ROUNDUP(ROW()/(COUNTA(A:A)-1),0))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Note that in this mapping, we traverse the table downwards and then across.  It is equally easy to traverse the table across and then downward.